# Need to have Excel reapply filter to the active sheet when navigating

Tags: vba, excel

I have one Excel sheet with navigation buttons to a variety of Student pages. Another sheet with a schedule. The student pages each of a data table of the schedule with a filter set to their name so that it shows only their values from the schedule data.

When I change the schedule, and navigate to the student page the new data is not automatically filtered.

How to I force Excel to re-apply that filter when the user navigates to the page.

I tried:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False 
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

and

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
```

without success. I can manually do this by clicking Data > Sort & Filter > Reapply in the Ribbon.  I want to code this into the navigation so they don't have to do that.

Comment: `.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` should work unless the entries you added do not match the filter you applied before.

Comment: I used this in the navigation button:  Worksheets("student_name").Activate then next link ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter and it does not reapply the filter.  Is this structured incorrectly? Its definitely not working.

Comment: Incorrect scope.  I put the table of data ahead of the .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter and it works.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a cell outside an Excel table as the trigger for filtering the table based on its value. I use a validation list that consisted of the values in the first column of the table to avoid typos. ***I also learned that the technique above only works when the ActiveCell is in the table you're trying to filter.*** I added code to keep the ActiveCell visible after the filter is reapplied.

Here's the code that worked for me in the Worksheet_Change event:

```
If Target = Range("Selected_Defined_Name") Then
' then there was a change to the selected defined name. So Reapply the filter to the Range_Names table
    With Target.Parent.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Activate
    End With
End If
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!

Comment: I believe `Target.Parent.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` would work irrespective of the active cell

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll have to try that.